# If $p(x) = \frac{1+x^2+x^4+\cdots + x^{2n-2}}{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}}$ is a polynomial in x, then find the possible value(s) of n

Tags: sequences-and-series

If 
$$ p(x) = \frac{1+x^2+x^4+\cdots + x^{2n-2}}{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}}$$
  is a polynomial in x, then find the possible value(s) of $n$.

---

We can notice that the numerator and the denominator are in GP. Hence, using the sum of a GP and simplifying we get,
$$p(x)=\frac{x^n+1}{x +1} $$
How to proceed from here?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391086/reducibility-of-x2n-x2n-2-cdots-x2-1).

Comment: If $n$ is odd, it's easy, because $x^n+1$ factorises.

Comment: And if $n$ is even, think about $p(-1)$.

Comment: @TonyK It would be really helpful if you give me an answer/elaborate the hint. I think the problem here is I am not aware of something that you think I know.

Comment: Just to see if I get it right: For $p(x)$ to be a polynomial, $x^n+1$ should have the factor $x+1$. This happens iff $n$ is a odd number. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x+1$ divides $x^n+1$ iff $-1$ is a root of $x^n+1$ iff $(-1)^n=-1$ iff $n$ is odd.

Comment: $x=-1$ is a root of $x+1$. So for $x-1$ to divide $x^n + 1$, we need the numerator in the form of $(x + 1)$(some other polynomial). Isn't?

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x^2}\frac{1-x}{1-x^n}=\frac{x^n+1}{x+1}$$

In the complete factorization of the numerator over $\mathbb{C}$, you would need a factor of $x+1$. So $-1$ would have to be a root of the numerator. So $(-1)^n=-1$. So $n$ would have to be odd.

Conversely, if $n$ is odd, then $n=2k+1$, and:
$$\frac{x^{2k+1}+1}{x+1}=x^{2k}-x^{2k-1}\pm\cdots-x+1=\sum_{j=0}^{2k}(-1)^jx^j$$